# Identifying a Surrogate Key

Tags: database, database-design, key, surrogate-key

I am modeling as practice an Airline Agency. I have a table "Passenger"

```
CREATE TABLE Passenger 
(
     confirmationNum INTEGER NOT NULL,
     flightNum       INTEGER NOT NULL,
     seatNum         INTEGER NOT NULL,
     name            VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     phone           VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

If I am correct I would say a passengers confirmation number and the flight number are surrogate keys. What I am wondering is an attribute such as seatNum in this case would also be a `surrogate key` or would that be considered a `natural key`.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree - a **surrogate key** is an artificially introduced key - typically just one column - that has no business meaning.

However, both `flightNum` and `confirmationNum` **do have** business meaning here in your model. If you use either of the two (or both together) as a key, then you're using a **natural** key.

A surrogate key would be a `PassengerID INT` that would be introduced that doesn't have any further business meaning other than uniquely identifying each passenger *within the IT system* (but not "in the real world").

Comment: SeatNum surely has business meaning to the airline selling (or over-selling) space on the specified flight. In the bigger picture it is likely a foreign key identifying unique seating space on a specific plane.

Answer (score 0):

SeatNum is not any kind of key. A seat is a seat is a seat. That is, there is no differentiation among seats. Even concepts such as "aisle seat" and "window seat" does not derive from any attribute of the seat itself. Within a flight, the Seatnum value must be unique, but such limited uniqueness is hardly sufficient to make it a candidate for *keyness*.

As you say this is practice, please permit a few more comments. Your table name suggests that the table contains a listing of passengers, yet ConfirmationNum, FlightNum and SeatNum describe, not a passenger, but a many-to-many relationship between a passenger and a flight (or trip). A flight can consist of many passengers and a reservation number can refer to a trip of one or many legs of flights.

So the fields ConfirmationNum, FlightNum and SeatNum would most logically be found in an intersection table like this one:

```
create table Trip(
  ConfirmationNum  int not null,
  FlightNum        int not null
    references Flights( ID ),
  SeatNum          int not null,
  PassengerNum     int not null
    references Passengers( ID )
  -- Possible other attriutes such as price and departure date
);
```

The Passengers table would consist of passenger data that would not vary from flight to flight or trip to trip.

A confirmation number could well refer to several different passengers -- a family or football team traveling together -- so the primary key of this table would be a composite key consisting of all four fields as shown.

Also, while it is true that a surrogate key *should* have no business meaning applied to it, it is also true that this rule is widely ignored. You have a perfectly good unique identifier so why not call it "confirmation number" or "account number" or any other of a wide variety of significant names?